# Is it possible to have a mouse left click after 2 seconds of inactivity - Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI in Tkinter, python, which can be navigated using a mouse cursor but no buttons/keys.

I am trying to solve a current problem of having the mouse left click without anyone pressing the physical mouse button or a key on the keyboard. I would like to have the mouse auto click after 2 seconds of inactivity.

For example i hover over a button and wait two seconds then the button is pressed.

I would like to say i have tried everything but i cant find anything to try. I thought about using the .invoke() function with a timing loop but i cant get it to run while my gui is open. ill show my gui code. Maybe i am doing something wrong, but if i place the .invoke function after the win.mainloop then it wont even run untill i close the gui tk window.

```
win = Tk()

# get the dimensions of the primary screen
app = wx.App(False)
w, h = wx.GetDisplaySize()
geometry = "%dx%d" % (w,h)
win.geometry(geometry)
win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
win.config(cursor="circle")

# get the grid image
bg = Image.open('grid_image.png')
img = bg.resize((w, h))
grid_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
image_label = Label(win, image=grid_img)
image_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# print an image of a green circle
gw = int(w/26)
gh = int(h/15)
g_circle = Image.open('green_circle.png')
g_img = g_circle.resize((gw,gh))
g_circle_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(g_img)
g_label = Label(win, image=g_circle_image)
g_label.place(x=w/8, y=h/8)
g_btn = Button(win, image=g_circle_image, command=win.destroy)
g_btn.place(x=(w/8), y=(h/8))

# print an image of a blue circle
bw = int(w/26)
bh = int(h/15)
b_circle = Image.open('circle.png')
b_img = b_circle.resize((bw,bh))
b_circle_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(b_img)
b_label = Label(win, image=b_circle_image)
b_label.place(x=(w/8)*5, y=(h/8)*5)
b_btn = Button(win, image=b_circle_image, command=win.destroy)
b_btn.place(x=(w/8)*5, y=(h/8)*5)

win.mainloop()
```

Any help with solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already seem to be confirming the option with `tk.Button().invoke()` you can use `tk.Button.bind('<Enter>', _onhover)` to detect the mouse over your button and `tk.Button.bind('<Leave>', _onleave)`

Define two functions like that:

```
def _onhover(event):
    global _current_button
    button = event.widget
    _current_button = button
    button.after(2000, lambda b=button: _invocation(b))

def _onleave(event):
    global _current_button
    _current_button = None

def _invocation(button):
    if _current_button is button:
        button.invoke()
```